# How to send RabbitMQ heartbeat frame using pika 1.2.0?

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq, pika

I am using `pika.BlockingConnection`. I use `basic_publish` and `channel.consume` for publishing and consuming messages.

Everything works well when `heartbeat` is set to `0` but when I set any value (60 for ex), RabbitMQ raises error:  `missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s`. How do I send heartbeat frame?

I use `pika==1.2.0` version.

Update: is any additional info needed?

Comment: Does it take longer to process your message than heartbeat timeout?

Comment: No, messages are just printed to logs

Answer (score 3):

You can send heartbeats manually using one of these methods:

```py
from pika import BlockingConnection

connection = BlockingConnection(*args, **kwargs)
connection._heartbeat_checker._send_heartbeat()
```

```py
from pika import frame

connection._send_frame(frame.Heartbeat())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've decided to try to rewrite my code with Select Connection Adapter so heartbeats will be sending automatically.

Comment: @pythonislovepythonislife Can you give more details on how to implement this with Select Connection ? Won't the app be blocked in the IO loop?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it exactly answers the question.

Comment: these two methods are not in `BlockingConnection` in `pika==1.3.2` if anyone else is trying this.

Comment: @dafrandle if you're using `BlockingConnection`, you may use `connection.process_data_events()` to prevent dropped heartbeat instead